# How to include AIDL-generated headers in native code in AOSP?

Tags: android, c++, android-source, aidl, android-soong

I have a native module under `/devices`:

```
- module
-- aidl
--- com
---- my
----- package
------ IMyInterface.aidl
-- Android.mk
-- Proxy.h
-- Proxy.cpp
```

I want to use binder in this module. My `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

$(call emugl-begin-shared-library,libMyModule)

LOCAL_AIDL_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/aidl

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    aidl/com/my/package/IMyInterface.aidl \
    Proxy.cpp \


LOCAL_HEADER_LIBRARIES := libbinder_headers \
                          libhidlbase_impl_internal \
                          libbase

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES :=       \
        libbinder               \
        libutils                \
        liblog                  \
        libcutils

$(call emugl-export,C_INCLUDES,$(LOCAL_PATH))
$(call emugl-import,libOpenglCodecCommon$(GOLDFISH_OPENGL_LIB_SUFFIX))

$(call emugl-end-module)
```

When I'm building it, it generates C++ headers, but they are located in the intermediates directory only:

```
$ ls out/target/product/emulator_x86_64/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libMyModule_intermediates/aidl-generated/include/com/my/package:

BnMyInterface.h  BpMyInterface.h  IMyInterface.h
```

How should I include them in my `Proxy.cpp`? If I just add `#include "IMyInterface.h"`, build system doesn't see it: `fatal error: 'IMyInterface.h' file not found`

Answer (score 1):

You may have to include it like `#include <com/my/package/BnMyInterface.h>`